# Не выводит изображение в Toast (Kotlin, IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toast

Решил сделать простенький пример на Kotlin - вывод Toast-сообщения с изображением. Сообщение без изображения выводит, а с изображением - нет. Приложение "вылетает". В LogCat ошибку не могу поймать - лог очищается автоматически. Вот пример кода (изображение лежит в директории drawable, разрешение 512 х 512):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener{
            val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Пора покормить кота!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0)

            val toastContainer = toast.view as ConstraintLayout
            val catImage = ImageView(this)
            catImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.hungry_cat)
            toastContainer.addView(catImage,0)
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Изменил ConstraintLayout на LinearLayout - все заработало. Код выглядит так:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener{

            val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Пора покормить кота!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0)

            val toastContainer = toast.view as LinearLayout
            val catImage = ImageView(this)
            catImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.hungry_cat)
            toastContainer.addView(catImage,0)
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```